# BigQuery - Group By with multiple fields extremely slow

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to group by multiple fields, such as Dates that spans through a few years with unique days (so 5*365 days maximum), and some unique IDs (a few thousand I believe).

The query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT
  cs.CriterionId,
  cs.AdGroupId,
  cs.CampaignId,
  cs.Date,
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Sum_Impressions,
  SUM(cs.Clicks) AS Sum_Clicks,
  SUM(cs.Interactions) AS Sum_Interactions,
  (SUM(cs.Cost) / 1000000) AS Sum_Cost,
  SUM(cs.Conversions) AS Sum_Conversions,
  cs.AdNetworkType1,
  cs.AdNetworkType2,
  cs.AveragePosition,
  cs.Device,
  cs.InteractionTypes
FROM
  `adwords.Keyword_{customer_id}` c
LEFT JOIN
  `adwords.KeywordBasicStats_{customer_id}` cs
ON
  c.ExternalCustomerId = cs.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
  AND c.ExternalCustomerId = {customer_id}
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

The keywordBasicStats table has around 700MB of data, and Keyword has around 50MB, and it's running for around a few hours now.

Not sure if there's a way to optimize this SQL query.

If anyone at Google is interested, the Job ID is:

```
blissful-land-197118:US.bquijob_668c014c_164b8710acc
```

Comment: This looks like an exploding join. Hard to know without access to the data - but once it finishes, can you share your details tab details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one(maybe some fix is required due to your columns datatypes):

```
SELECT
  cs.CriterionId,
  cs.AdGroupId,
  cs.CampaignId,
  cs.Date,
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Sum_Impressions,
  SUM(cs.Clicks) AS Sum_Clicks,
  SUM(cs.Interactions) AS Sum_Interactions,
  (SUM(cs.Cost) / 1000000) AS Sum_Cost,
  SUM(cs.Conversions) AS Sum_Conversions,
  cs.AdNetworkType1,
  cs.AdNetworkType2,
  cs.AveragePosition,
  cs.Device,
  cs.InteractionTypes
FROM
  `adwords.Keyword_{customer_id}` c
INNER JOIN
  `adwords.KeywordBasicStats_{customer_id}` cs
ON
  c.ExternalCustomerId = cs.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
  AND c.ExternalCustomerId = {customer_id}
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

UNION ALL

SELECT
  cs.CriterionId,
  cs.AdGroupId,
  cs.CampaignId,
  cs.Date,
  0.0 AS Sum_Impressions,
  0.0 AS Sum_Clicks,
  0.0 AS Sum_Interactions,
  0.0 AS Sum_Cost,
  0.0 AS Sum_Conversions,
  cs.AdNetworkType1,
  cs.AdNetworkType2,
  cs.AveragePosition,
  cs.Device,
  cs.InteractionTypes
FROM
  `adwords.Keyword_{customer_id}` c
LEFT JOIN
  `adwords.KeywordBasicStats_{customer_id}` cs
ON
  c.ExternalCustomerId = cs.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE cs.ExternalCustomerId IS NULL 
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
  AND c.ExternalCustomerId = {customer_id}
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

Comment: The grouped combinations that does not exist in one group but exists in another group actually creates constant values from somewhere.

Comment: Maybe this is a logic issue from the original query? Because i only change left to inner - the lefts not found are always nulls and nulls are always ignored from aggregates - equal to sum(0)=0. The union i have is to bring groups that are all nulls - to bring empty groups in other words

Answer (score 1):

I think, what makes this query extremely slow is ORDER BY
Just remove it and try again

Comment: After 3000 seconds and counting, it is still suck in the same place of JOIN+

Comment: Maybe you have a lot of skew--try using APPROX_TOP_COUNT over the customer IDs in each table to see the counts of the top IDs.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard If there's a lot of skew, then how should I optimize the query?

Comment: For example, if you have some "dummy" customer ID that appears frequently in the data, you could explicitly filter it out if the results for it aren't interesting. Otherwise you basically end up with a cross join, which produces a huge number of rows. See also https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns#unbalanced_joins